# Get derived class property from parent without repetitive casting

Tags: c#

I am trying to work-around an annoyance, caused by design failure in the data model structure. Refactoring is not an option, because EF goes crazy. ASP.NET 4.6 framework.

The structure is as follows:

```
class Course
{
     // properties defining a Course object. Example: Marketing course
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

class CourseInstance
{
    // properties that define an Instance of course. Example: Marketing course, January
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}

class InternalCourseInstance : CourseInstance
{
    // Additional business logic properties. Example : Entry course - Marketing program
    public bool IsEntry { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public Course Course { get; set; }
}

class OpenCourseInstance : CourseInstance
{
    // Separate branch of instance. Example - Marketing course instance
    public int Price { get; set; }    

    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

I bet you can already see the flaw? Indeed, for an unknown reason, someone decided to put `CourseId` and its navigational property on the derived types, instead of parent. Now every time I want to access the `Course` from `CourseInstance`, I have do do something like:

```
x.course => courseInstance is InternalCourseInstance
    ? (courseInstance as InternalCourseInstance).Course
    : (courseInstance as OpenCourseInstance).Course;
```

You can see how this can become really ugly with several more course instance types that derive from `CourseInstance`.

I am looking for a way to short-hand that, essentially create a method or expression which does it internally. There is one more problem however - it has to be translatable to SQL, since more often then not this casting is used on `IQueryable`.

The closest I came to the solution is:

```
// CourseInstance.cs
public static Expression<Func<CourseInstance, Course>> GetCourseExpression =>
    t => t is OpenCourseInstance
        ? (t as OpenCourseInstance).Course
        : (t as InternalCrouseInstance).Course
```

This should work, however sometimes I need `Id` or `Name` of `Course`. And there is no way, as far as I can tell - to expand this Expression in specific circumstances to return `Id` or `Name`.

I can easily do it inside a method, but then it fails on LINQ to Entities, understandably.

I know it's a project-specific problem, however at this stage it cannot be fixed, so I am trying to find a decent work around.

---

### Solution

Firstly, thanks to **HimBromBeere** for his answer and patience. I couldn't get his generic overload to work, in my case it was throwing as you might see in the discussion below his answer. Here is how I solved it eventually:

#### CourseInstance.cs

```
public static Expression<Func<CourseInstance, TProperty> GetCourseProperty<TProperty>(
    Expression<Func<Course, TProperty>> propertySelector)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CourseInstance), "ci");

    var isInternalCourseInstance = Expression.TypeIs(parameter, typeof(InternalCourseInstance);

    // 1) Cast to InternalCourseInstance and get Course property
    var getInternalCourseInstanceCourse = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
        Expression.TypeAs(parameter, typeof(InternalCourseInstance)), typeof(InternalCourseInstance).GetProperty(nameof(InternalCourseInstance.Course)));

    var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body).Member.Name;

    // 2) Get value of <propertyName> in <Course> object.
    var getInternalCourseInstanceProperty = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
        getInternalCourseInstanceCourse, typeof(Course).GetProperty(propertyName);

    // Repeat steps 1) and 2) for OpenCourseInstance ...

    var expression = Expression.Condition(isInternalCourseInstance, getInternalCourseInstanceProperty, getOpenCourseInstanceProperty);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<CourseInstance, TProperty(expression, parameter);
```

#### Usage

```
// his first suggestion - it works, retrieving the `Course` property of `CourseInstance`
var courses = courseInstancesQuery.Select(GetCourse()) 

// My modified overload above. 
var courseNames = courseInstancesQuery.Select(GetCourseProperty<string>(c => c.Name));
```

#### Thoughts

The problem with the suggested implementation in my opinion is within the `Expression.Call` line. Per [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Call_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression___):

> Creates a MethodCallExpression that represents a call to a method that takes arguments.

However my desired expression contains no method calls - so I removed it and it worked. Now I simply use the delegate to extract the desired property's name and get that with another `MemberAccessExpression`.

This is only my interpretation though. Happy to get corrected, if I am wrong.

**Remarks**: I recommend caching the `typeof` calls in private fields, instead of calling them every time you build the expression. Also this can work for more then two derived classes (in my case `InternalCourseInstance` and `OpenCourseInstance`), you just need an extra `ConditionalExpression`(s).

### Edit

I've edited the code section - it seems `Expression.Convert` is not supported by EntityFramework, however `Expression.TypeAs` works just the same.

Comment: I´m not sure if this works for EF, but could you go for `dynamic` turning your expression into something like `Expression<Func<dynamic, Course>>`? Not ideal, but as your design is broken anyway. In fact I hate myself for even suggesting it...

Comment: @HimBromBeere I thought of that, however it does not solve the problem on conceptual level. I still don't have a way of getting the `Id` of `Course`, if I need. And more often then not this is required in*LINQ* expressions and *AutoMapper* configurations, which means I cannot simply get the `Id` with follow up `Select` statement, for example. Please don't have yourself, I've expressed enough hate on this subject already :)

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the expression using an expression-tree:

```
Expression<Func<CourseInstance, Course>> CreateExpression()
{
    // (CourseInstance x) => x is InternalCourseInstance ? ((InternalCourseInstance)x).Course : ((OpenCourseInstance).x).Course

    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CourseInstance), "x");
    Expression expr = Expression.TypeIs(param, typeof(InternalCourseInstance));
    var cast1Expr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Convert(param, typeof(InternalCourseInstance)), typeof(InternalCourseInstance).GetProperty(nameof(InternalCourseInstance.Course)));
    var cast2Expr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Convert(param, typeof(OpenCourseInstance)), typeof(OpenCourseInstance).GetProperty(nameof(OpenCourseInstance.Course)));
    expr = Expression.Condition(expr, cast1Expr, cast2Expr);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<CourseInstance, Course>>(expr, param);
}
```

ow you can use this expression by compiling it and call it:

```
var func = CreateExpression().Compile();
var courseInstance = new InternalCourseInstance { Course = new Course { Name = "MyCourse" } };
var result = func(courseInstance);
```

In order to get the `CourseId` or the `Name` from the instance you have to introduce a delegate that expects an instance of `Course` and returns any arbitrary type `T`. This means you´d need to add a call to that delegate in yoour expression-tree:

```
expr = Expression.Call(null, func.Method, expr);
```

The `null` is important as your delegate that points to an anonymous method is translated to a static method from your compiler. If the delegate on the other hand points to a named non-static method, you should of course provide an instance for which this method is then called:

```
expr = Expression.Call(instanceExpression, func.Method, expr);
```

Be aware that your compiled method now returns a `T`, not a `Course`, so your final method looks like this:

```
Expression<Func<CourseInstance, T>> CreateExpression<T>(Func<Course, T> func)
{
    // x => func(x is InternalCourseInstance ? ((InternalCourseInstance)x).Course : ((OpenCourseInstance).x).Course)

    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CourseInstance), "x");
    Expression expr = Expression.TypeIs(param, typeof(InternalCourseInstance));
    var cast1Expr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Convert(param, typeof(InternalCourseInstance)), typeof(InternalCourseInstance).GetProperty(nameof(InternalCourseInstance.Course)));
    var cast2Expr = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Convert(param, typeof(OpenCourseInstance)), typeof(OpenCourseInstance).GetProperty(nameof(OpenCourseInstance.Course)));
    expr = Expression.Condition(expr, cast1Expr, cast2Expr);
    expr = Expression.Call(null, func.Method, expr);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<CourseInstance, T>>(expr, param);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand correctly - `result` will contain the `Course` object, regardless if I pass `CourseInstance`, `InternalCourseInstance` or `OpenCourseInstance`? Would that work in LINQ to Entities? This goes a bit deeper then my experience. Will give it a go ASAP.

Comment: @Alex Me neither, however I assume EF is one of the reasons to even think about expression-trees at all. Otherwise you could just create the method as written in your question already. And yes, `result` contains an instance of `Course`.

Comment: Still can't get `Expression.Call` to work. It looks like this: `Expression.Call(null, propertySelector.Method, outerExpression)` and throws **Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: method** exception

Comment: I am not sure what is `static` and what is not. My whole Expression was defined as a static method, attached to my Data model - `CourseInstance`, but this shouldn't be a problem and indeed it is not. According to the compiler - `propertySelector.Method` is supposed to be `null`, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Your non-generic suggestion also throws: 
**Unable to cast the type 'CourseInstance' to type 'InternalCourseInstance'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.**

Comment: Depending on what delegate you provide to `CreateExpression` you should either provide `null` as first param for `Expression.Call` for a delegate pointing to a static method or an anonymous method, or the instance onto which to call the method if it´s an instance-method.

Comment: How do you suggest I call your proposed solution? Here is what I have `CreateExpression<string>(c => c.Name). As far as I understand I am calling `.Name` on instance, so I have to pass value to the first argument of `Call`. Since my delegate is of Type <Func<Course, T>, I did the equivalent of this: `Expression.Call(expr, func.Method)` (using variable names from your example), but this throws **Method System.String<{action-name}> declared on {controller-type} cannot be called with instance of type CourseInstance**. This has me dead in the water - why is it calling System.String with my action?

Comment: If you use `(CreateExpression(c => c.Name)` the provided param is an anonymous method whis is translated to a static method by the compiler. Thus you have to use `Expression.Call(null, func.Method, expr)`.

Comment: This is what I originally tried, but I get **Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.
Parameter name: method; property: method** exception. And when I inspect `func.Method` is is `System.String<Show>b_11_0(Data.Models.CourseInstance.Course)`. `Show` is the name of the `Action` method, where I call the expression. I don't understand.

Comment: Me neither, what is an action-method? **How** precisely do you call `CreateExpression`?

Comment: It's an ASP.NET MVC app, Action method is controller method, which returns view. Exact Expression definition: `public static Expression<Func<CourseInstance, TProperty>> GetCourseExpression<TProperty>(Func<Course, TProperty> propertySelector)`. Exact call is - `queryable.Select(GetCourseExpression<string>(c => c.Name));` However I think the delegate is fine, because I tested with simpler delegates that return number, and they do function correctly and when inspected - they look exactly the same.

Comment: Would you mind moving this to chat? As it's getting a bit lengthly?

Comment: Got it working. Editing my question now :) Thanks for the help.