# Create Expression tree that defines only lambda body

Tags: c#, delegates, expression-trees

As stated by the title - I want to define an expression, which describes only the body of a method. Example:

```
// Definition
public Expression<T> SomeExpression<T>() { ... }

// Usage
entities.Select(e => e.SomeExpression<int>())

// Instead of 
entities.Select(SomeExpression<int>())
```

I know I can define a delegate Expression as

```
Expression<Func<int>> SomeExpression() { ... }
```

But since this describes a full-fat delegate I have to use it as `.Select(SomeExpression())`. This is a problem, because the only way I can seamlessly use it is to attach `SomeExpression` on the entity instance itself.

I know this makes little sense - in short, I am trying to implement a workaround for a stupid mistake made long ago in the project. Proper fix is out of the question.

**Remarks:**

- `SomeExpression` has to be defined on the entity instance `e`
- `SomeExpression` has to operate on `e` (I am thinking of `Expression.Consntant(this)`)
- `SomeExpression` has to be supported by *EntityFramework*
- `SomeExpression` has to return generic value, e.g. `string` or `int`

#### More information

I am trying to solve a poor inheritence issue - I have an entity (**Training**), which has foreign key to another entity (**Course**). The training entity is composed of a base class(of the same name - **Training**) and several derived ones (**Instances**). The problem is that the **foreign key**, which is absolutely identical for all, is held in a property of the derived classes, instead of the base one. Since I have a common layer of services, every time I get a **Training** entity i have to perform several conditional casts to all of the derived classes, to get to the **Course** entity.

`SomeExpression` itself effectively translates to something like

```
t => t is InternalInstance
    ? (t as InternalInstance).Course,
    : t is OpenInstance
         ? // So on an so forth...
```

You can read in more details in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226356/get-derived-class-property-from-parent-without-repetitive-casting-solved/53226907?noredirect=1#comment93441839_53226907).

Why wouldn't a lambda work in my case? I have omitted generics in the question, to keep it simple, however in my case `SomeExpression` and its class has to depend on several generic parameters, since I have several web projects in my solution, each coming with its own **Course** and **Instance** types.

That is why ideal place for this expression would be on the **Training** type - it already has the required generic parameters. If I don't put it there I have to create a **service** and use the **container** to resolve them. Then I would have to inject this service everywhere I want to use this mapping - mainly common services and **view models**. Adding it to the common services isn't a problem, but is obtrusive, as in you need additional dependency, just to perform the mapping. The **view models** are problematic, since they use *AutoMapper* configuration, to encapsulate the mapping and keep it inside. *AutoMapper* creates and caches the maps well before the container is up and running, which resolves in **NullReference**. There are ways to provide the service runtime, but that increases the boilerplate in both view model and controller. At this point using the expression to get **Course** is more of a hassle, then convenient.

That's the context. I tried to keep it short, but there are a lot of obstacles.

Comment: "not really", however: expression trees are very powerful and flexible (and can be constructed in several ways) - if you can give a more complete example of *why* you want to do this (i.e. a scenario in which it would be useful), it is almost certainly possible to get it to do what you want *in some way*.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks. I have edited the question to provide context.

Comment: The problem is that when you do `Select(e => e.Whatever())`, `Whatever` is not called, but simply "marked" as `MethodCall` inside the expression tree. Which makes it non translatable, because EF translation is based on knowledge - any unknowns are simply exceptions (EF6) or client evaluation (EF Core). Shortly, even if you somehow solve the C# syntactical part, you can't solve the issue in general w/o expression tree post processing. Basically what LinqKit `AsExoandable` and NeinLinq `ToInjectable` do.

Comment: @IvanStoev I see. I've looked at LinqKit, but its not all around solid solution, unfortunately. It would be fine inside services, but if I use `Invoke` in the view-model mapping, I have no way of guaranteeing that `AsExpandable` is called on the query, before the mapping. Essentially an invitation for runtime exceptions.

Comment: You are using `Expression`s in ways that aren't possible, making it hard for me to follow what you are trying to accomplish, e.g. you can't do `e.`(an `Expression`) or (an `Expression`)`()`.

Comment: Yea, @NetMage, thought so. I am looking into using NeinLinq, as suggested. Thanks.